# BigQuery SQL - Create New Column Based on the Max Value from Multiple Columns

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table contains info about customers and their purchases amount of each type of food. I want to create new columns that is the most freq type of food they have purchased. Is there an efficient way to do this?

I tried using case when and do one-to-one comparison, but it got very tedious.

Sample data:

| Cust_ID | apple_type1 | apple_type2 | apple_type3 | apple_type4 | apple_type5 | apple_type6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 3 | 6 | 1 |
| 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 3 | 4 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 4 | 5 | 5 | 5 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 5 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

--WANT

| Cust_ID | freq_apple_type_buy |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | type5 |
| 2 | type4 and type6 |
| 3 | type1 |
| 4 | type1 and type2 and type3 |
| 5 | unknown |

Comment: OMG thank you so much! what did you edit to make this look right?

Comment: Are you able / willing to change your source data model? If you had normalised this data (three columns; cust_id, apple_type, quantity) then this would be trivial.

Comment: The edit to make the tables render correctly was to have a blank line before each table.

Comment: so, if I have 3 columns in my original data (three columns; cust_id, apple_type, quantity), to get the most freq apple type buy, I can just do:

select cust_id, apply_type, max(quantity) from xxx group by cust_id, apply_type?

What if there are multiple types that have the same buy amount and I want to categorize it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select Cust_ID, if(count(1) = any_value(all_count), 'unknown', string_agg(type, ' and ')) freq_apple_type_buy
from (
  select *, count(1) over(partition by Cust_ID) all_count
  from (
    select Cust_ID, replace(arr[offset(0)], 'apple_', '') type,cast(arr[offset(1)] as int64) value
    from data t,
    unnest(split(translate(to_json_string((select as struct * except(Cust_ID) from unnest([t]))), '{}"', ''))) kv,
    unnest([struct(split(kv, ':') as arr)])
  )
  where true qualify 1 = rank() over(partition by Cust_ID order by value desc)
)
group by Cust_ID
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This uses UNPIVOT to turn your columns in to rows.  Then uses RANK() to assign each row a rank, which means if multiple rows are matched in quantity, they share the same rank.

It then selects only the products with rank=1 (possibly multiple rows, if multiple products are tied for first place)

```
WITH
  normalised_and_ranked AS
(
  SELECT
    cust_id,
    product,
    qty,
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY cust_id ORDER BY qty DESC) AS product_rank,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cust_id ORDER BY qty DESC) AS product_row
  FROM
     yourData
  UNPIVOT(
    qty FOR product IN (apple_type1, apple_type2, apple_type3, apple_type4, apple_type5, apple_type6)
  )
)
SELECT
  cust_id,
  CASE WHEN qty = 0 THEN NULL ELSE product END   AS product,
  CASE WHEN qty = 0 THEN NULL ELSE qty END   AS qty
FROM
  normalised_and_ranked
WHERE
  (product_rank = 1 AND qty > 0)
  OR
  (product_row = 1)
```

Edit: fudge added to ensure row of nulls returned if all qty are 0.

(Normally I'd just not return a row for such customers.)